# I have a issue with creating a form in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm having an error when using `handleChange("firstName")`

I tried to call the function in others ways

```
    const handleChange = input => e => {
      this.setState({ [input]: e.target.value });
    };
```

```
export class FormUserDetails extends Component {
  continue = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    debugger;
    this.props.nextStep();
  };
  render() {
    const { values, handleChange } = this.props;
    return (
      <div class="page">
        <h2 class="box-title">Who are you ?</h2>
        <form onSubmit={this.continue}>
          <div class="content">
            <input
              class="form-input"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Surname"
              name="firstname"
              defaultValue={values.firstName}
              onChange={handleChange("firstName")}
              required
            />
          </div>
          <input type="submit" value="Next" class="submit-button" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default FormUserDetails;
```

```
TypeError: handleChange is not a function
FormUserDetails.render
src/components/form/FormUserDetails.js:27
```

```
  24 |   placeholder="Surname"
  25 |   name="firstname"
  26 |   defaultValue={values.firstName}
> 27 |   onChange={handleChange("firstName")}
     | ^  28 |   required
  29 | />
  30 | <input
```

Thanks you for your help

Comment: Are you sending handleChange function as prop to FormUserDetails ?

Comment: Can you post FormUserDetails component's parent component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to return a function, just do:

```
handleChange = e => {
  this.setState({
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value
  });
};
```

And then you can call it from `onChange` without params, provided you change the input name to `firstName` instead of `firstname`:

```
onChange={this.props.handleChange}
```

Comment: But the value doesn't get stored in the UserForm state

Comment: React Developer Tools in the chrome console

Comment: Add your userForm component to the question.

Comment: Ok, so it'd be `this.props.handleChange`, and make sure your input has `name='firstName'` with proper case. Plus when defining `handleChange`, don't use const. Updated the answer.

Comment: so let handleChange ?

Comment: No, it's a class instance method, just `handleChange = e => {`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions

Comment: Yes, it's what I did first but I had an error :  'handleChange' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Comment: ahh, I see now. You've defined it inside `nextStep` method. You need to define it on the same level as `nextStep`.

Comment: Oh yes indeed, but I still can't get the values in the UserForm state

Comment: Thanks you for your precious help

Answer (score 0):

Another solution like the official docs

```
  handleChange(event) {
this.setState({value: event.target.value});
```

}

And you call it

```
render() {
return (
  <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <label>
      Name:
      <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
);
```

}